# A subadditive bijection on the positive reals

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

I posed some time ago [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827433/a-subadditive-bijection-on-the-positive-reals) on MSE, which I am proposing also here since we got no definitive answer.

> **Question.** Does there exist a subadditive bijection $f$ of the positive reals $(0,\infty)$ such that
>   $$
> \liminf_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=0 \,\,\,\text{ and }\,\,\,\limsup_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=1\,?
> $$

As it is written in the comments therein, the answer would be affirmative if:
(i) "bijection" is replaced with "injection";
(ii) "$\limsup_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=1$" is replaced with "$\limsup_{x\to 0^+}f(x)\neq 0$"; and
(iii) "$\liminf_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=0$" is replaced with "$\liminf_{x\to 0^+}f(x)\neq 0$".